# Two threads using the same websock handle- does it cause any issue?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, websocket, winhttp

We are having a C++ application to send and receive WebSocket messages

- One thread to send the message (using [`WinHttpWebSocketSend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707329.aspx))
- the second thread to receive (using [`WinHttpWebSocketReceive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh707328.aspx))

But the same WebSocket handle is used across these 2 threads. Will it cause any problems? I don't know if we have to handle it another way. It works in our application - we are able to send and receive messages - but I don't know if it will have any problem in the production environment. Any one has better ideas?

Comment: If the threads doesn't *both* send, or *both* receive, then for normal sockets that would not be a problem. Web-sockets are more complicated so it really depends on the functions themselves, and what happens in the framework-level beyond your control. Unfortunately the MSDN documentation doesn't say anything specific that I could find, and that would cause me to use some form of synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Like most platforms, nearly all Windows API system calls do not provide thread barriers beyond preventing simultaneous access to the key parts of the kernel. While I could not say for sure (the documentation doesn't seem to answer your explicit question) I would be surprised if the [WinHTTP API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384252(v=vs.85).aspx) provides barriers that prevent multiple threads from stepping on each other (so to speak)--particularly because it's really just a "helper" API that uses the somewhat lower level Winsock stuff directly--and I would take it upon myself to implement the necessary barriers.

I'm also wondering why you're using threads in this manner to begin with. I know essentially nothing about the WinHTTP API, but I did notice [WINHTTP_OPTION_ASSURED_NON_BLOCKING_CALLBACKS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx) which leads me to believe that you can implement an asynchronous approach which would prevent any thread-safety issues to begin with (and probably be much faster and memory efficient).

It appears that the callback mechanism for WinHTTP is rather expressive. See [WINHTTP_STATUS_CALLBACK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383917(v=vs.85).aspx). Presumably, you can simply use non-blocking operation, create an event listener, and associate the connection handle with `dwContext`. No threads involved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We used threads so that we dont need to blcok the main thread while waiting for the message to arrive. I think we can implement callback for receiving the messages. But I am not sure, how to make the sending messages asynchronous other than using the threads?

Comment: In a non-blocking I/O model, the main thread wouldn't block. It polls for I/O events either directly or indirectly (via registered callbacks). At some point in the program it asks the API, "Hey, do you have anything for me?" and the API answers with "yes" (potentially firing off callbacks) or "no". In the Windows API, many times this polling happens during the main window message loop somewhat invisibly. Again, I know nothing about WinHTTP, but a cursory glance makes it look like you can do something like that.

Comment: Well, let me clarify a tad by what I mean by "not block"... it would block when it's doing CPU work, but not wait for I/O. Generally exactly what you want for something like socket I/O as long as you're not sitting and waiting for something like image resizing or some other expensive task. Most "handle message and respond" type tasks take essentially no time. If it would take time, create a thread pool of workers in a consumer/producer model that wouldn't block the main thread and whose job is to do those expensive things.

Comment: how about sending the messages. Do we need to have a separate thread for it? or it can be sent from the main thread? The main issue we are having is this. We are having a single WinHTTP/WebSocket handle, which we need to use for sending as well as receiving. I understood your idea of using the callback to receive. But what about sending the messages? What is your idea on that?